# The session has expired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my web application when the session got expires, I have to refresh (F5) the web page again to continue using the application, otherwise, it will return an error "OOps something went wrong, session expired"

I did something like that:

```
http.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1)
.expiredUrl("/start")
.and().invalidSessionUrl("/start");
```

Application:

```
server.port: 8080
```

But that works only if I refresh the website, otherwise it will not works
Any advice?

Comment: please show application.properties

Comment: @AshokKumarN I put it, but the everything what I have is a information about port.

Answer (score 0):

Put a keepalive script in place that either resets the timeout on your session, or checks if the session has expired and automatically redirects the user.

```
var pingFrequency = 30;

// initializes the keep-alive settings
$(function() {
    setKeepAliveTimeout();
});

// executes a ping after pingFrequency
function setKeepAliveTimeout() {
    setTimeout(keepAlivePing, pingFrequency * 1000);
}

// executes the keepAlivePing, schedules a new ping if required
function keepAlivePing() {
    $.get("/keep-alive/ping", function (response) {
        if (/* check the response conditions */) {
            setKeepAliveTimeout();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do that in java?

Comment: Not with standard http, since you have no way of detecting if the user still has the webpage open. This would let you know that from the user's side. You can probably do something with Reactjs, or websockets, or some other way to keep a live connection running between client and server, but unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with that (and it seems overkill if you just want to do this with it, but if you're already using any of those, go for it!)

Comment: But if user press on some button that is turn on some acction, that cannot still redirect him to login/start website when the session expired?

Comment: If the session is kept alive like this, and the session timeout is higher than the pingFrequency, then the user should never see the login page unless they close the window. To be clear: if you configure session management to close sessions after 5 minutes of inactivity, this will cause some activity every 30 seconds, so the session stays active as long as the browser window stays open (and for 5 minutes after it closes).